# weak law of large numbers, exponential(3) distribution

Tags: probability, law-of-large-numbers

I'm going through an example in my textbook but can't seem to follow every step.

Let $ W_1, W_2,... $ be i.i.d with distribution $ Exponential(3). $ Prove that for some
$n$, we have 
$ P(W_1+W_2+...+W_n < \frac{n}{2}) > 0.999. $

The solution in the book says:

$ P(W_1+W_2+...+W_n < \frac{n}{2}) = 1-P(W_1+...+W_n \geq \frac{n}{2}) \geq (**)$ 
$ 1-P(|\frac{1}{n}(W_1+...+W_n)-1/3| \geq 1/6). $

What I don't understand is the inequality (**), I simply don't get why it's there, and I also don't understand why there is $ \frac{1}{6} $ in the last row (why have they chosen $\varepsilon$ as $\frac{1}{6}$ and not any other number larger than 0?). What I do understand is that $  P(|\frac{1}{n}(W_1+...+W_n)-\frac{1}{3}| > \varepsilon) = 0 $ and hence, it has been shown that $ P(W_1+...+W_n < \frac{n}{2}) \geq 1 $ as well as larger than 0.999.

Comment: The inequality $x \ge n/2$ is equivalent to $x/n-1/3\ge 1/6$, which, obviously, implies that $|x/n-1/3|\ge 1/6$. The last two sentences are incorrect: this probability is not zero, but tends to zero as $n\to\infty$. Then, naturally, it is less than $0.001$ for all $n$ large enough.

Comment: To me it isn't clear though how $ x \geq \frac{n}{2} $ is equivalent to $ \frac{x}{n} - \frac{1}{3} \geq \frac{1}{6}. $

Comment: Oh, sorry, now I get it!